# How did Clu plan to bring his army into the real world?

Tags: tron-legacy

During TRON-Legacy we learn that Clu wanted to invade the real world with his army of programs to impose his order. We see him moving a large aircraft carrier style craft towards the portal, at which time Kevin and Sam realize he means to pilot the whole construct with the army through it.

Nice plan, but it seems to have a major flaw. The portal empties out into the basement of the arcade in a rather small room. How exactly did Clu plan to rememdy the issue of inadequate space within which to park his technological terror?

Answer (score 5):

Clu comes out first, accesses the situation and presumably moves the laser and associated equipment to someplace with more space.  He had Flynn's disk, so extensive knowledge of external world conditions was available to him.

Or it could be that the carrier with the soldiers on it was a visual metaphor like so much else of what we saw on the grid.  Clu and his minions might manifest into the real world as [parasitic computations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parasitic_computing) on the Internet, giving them a kind of freedom and immortality that they could never have on a single server in some guy's basement.

Or it could be that Clu isn't in fact a human-level AI at all and once he's faced with the complexity and data density of the real world, he'd blunder about like a gibbon in our society.  For all the razzle-dazzle of the game grid, the culture and social interactions there were cartoonish compared to the real world, and Clu would have no way of knowing that.

Comment: `He had Flynn's disk, so extensive knowledge of external world conditions was available to him ... For all the razzle-dazzle of the game grid, the culture and social interactions there were cartoonish compared to the real world, and Clu would have no way of knowing that.` he did have one way of knowing.

Comment: If Clu gets weapons, vehicles, etc, into the real world, would they actually work?

Comment: @user35971 I'd guess so.  Quorra was a new life form and she worked.

Comment: Clu starts shouting and tossing a killer frisbee around, and is shot in the head by the police eight minutes and fifty-two seconds after exiting the grid.